# Stepping Through Python Turtle Recursive Function

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to improve my understanding of recursion, and visual representations are very helpful for me. I've got a recursive tree-drawing function and I'd like to be able to step through it and contemplate what happens at each stage. I've found IDLE's debugger, but I can't seem to make it stop once the call to the recursive function has been made. Also, when I step through the code, several windows open up from the turtle module and it all becomes a right mess.

Is this possible using IDLE, or should I perhaps resort to manually coding the pauses and log-info I need to understand this function? As a secondary question, can anyone explain how this code works? It seems to draw all the right hand branches first, which I can follow, but then what it does starts to seem like voodoo.

Code below:

```
import turtle

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.speed(1)
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(75,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: I don't use IDLE, so I can't help you there. The key to understanding `tree` is that at the completion of drawing of a (sub)tree the turtle has been put back to its original position and heading. So each recursive call doesn't disturb the current position and heading.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways that may help you visualize the steps.

The first is to add `t.stamp()` at the beginning of your `tree` function. This will give another visual indicator of each time the `tree` function is being called.

```
def tree(branchLen, t):
if branchLen > 5:
    t.stamp()
    t.forward(branchLen)
    ...
```

You already have the turtle's speed as slow as it will go.  Another way to slow down the action is to import the `time` module and use the `sleep` function.  If using this solution, I would recommend using the `sleep` call just before you call `tree` recursively.

```
import turtle
import time

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15,t)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)
```

You could even combine the two methods to differentiate when tree is being called for the right and left branches (the first and second recursive calls.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of visualizing what's happening without modifying your original recursive subroutine.  First, we change the one `backward()` to a `forward()` by reversing the sign.  Then we smash a new implementation of `forward()` that changes pen color, draws the line, waits for a carriage return at the console, undoes what it just did and finally does what the original `forward()` would have done:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def visible_forward(self, distance):
    if self.isdown():
        color = self.pencolor()
        self.pencolor('red')

        forward_original(self, distance)

        input("step> ")

        self.pencolor(color)
        forward_original(self, -distance)

    forward_original(self, distance)

def tree(branchLen, t):
    if branchLen > 5:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-15, t)
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-15, t)
        t.right(20)
        t.forward(-branchLen)

myWin = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

forward_original, Turtle.forward = Turtle.forward, visible_forward

turtle.speed('slowest')

turtle.left(90)
turtle.penup()
turtle.backward(100)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.color("green")
tree(75, turtle)

myWin.mainloop()
```

[image]

I only recommend this as a learning or debugging trick, not for finished code.